# finding out if a family of sets constructed by a function $i:2^X \to 2^X$ is a topology for X

Tags: general-topology

I've been working on the  following problem:

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ and $i:2^X\to 2^X$ be a function such that

1. $X=i(X)$
2. $i(A) \subseteq A$;   $ \forall A\in 2^X$
3. $i(A)=i(i(A))$;   $ \forall A\in 2^X$
4. $i(A\cap B)=i(A)\cap i(B)$;     $ \forall A,B\in 2^X$

Does $\tau =\{i(A): A\subseteq X\}$ define a topology for $X$?

This problem had other parts but this is where I'm stuck. We can easily see that $X,\emptyset \in \tau$ by (1) and (2) and that for a finite group of sets in $\tau$ the intersection is also in $\tau$ using (4). But one condition deciding whether or not $\tau$ is a topology is left; and that is if the union of a group of sets of $\tau$ is in $\tau$. I think $\tau$ is not a topology for $X$ and have been trying to find a group of sets $\{i(A_k)\}$ such that $\cup i(A_k)\neq i(A)$ for all $A\subseteq X$; but I've failed miserably.

Also I'm pretty tired so if you see any mistakes please forgive me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s useful to prove first that if $A\subseteq B$, then $i(A)\subseteq i(B)$. This follows from (3): if $A\subseteq B$, then $A\cap B=A$, so

$$i(A)=i(A\cap B)=i(A)\cap i(B)\,,$$

and therefore $i(A)\subseteq i(B)$.

Now suppose that $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\tau$, and let $U=\bigcup\mathscr{A}$; in order to show that $U\in\tau$, we must show that $i(U)=U$, and since $i(U)\subseteq U$, we need only show that $U\subseteq i(U)$. Suppose that $x\in U$; then $x\in A$ for some $A\in\mathscr{A}$, and $i(A)=A$, so $x\in i(A)\subseteq i(U)$. And $x\in U$ was arbitrary, so $U\subseteq i(U)$, and we’re done.